# Does Spark incur the same amount of overhead as Hadoop for vnodes?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I just read https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974621/260805. Does Spark (specifically Datastax's Cassandra Spark connector) incur the same amount of overhead as Hadoop when reading from a Cassandra cluster? I know Spark uses threads more heavily than Hadoop does.

Comment: Running a smaller unscientific benchmark to test this. If noone else responds, I will at least share my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give three separate answers. I apologize for the rather unstructured answer, but it's been building up over time:

### A previous answer:

Here's one potential answer: [Why not enable virtual node in an Hadoop node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969329/why-not-enable-virtual-node-in-an-hadoop-node/19974621?noredirect=1#comment48001100_19974621). I quote:

> > Does this also apply to Spark?
>
> No, if you're using the official DataStax spark-cassandra-connector. It can process multiple token ranges in a single Spark task. There is still some minor performance hit, but not as huge as with Hadoop.

### A production benchmark

We ran a Spark job against a vnode-enabled Cassandra (Datastax Enterprise) datacenter with 3 nodes. The job took 9.7 hours. Running the same job on for *slightly* less data, using 5 non-vnode nodes, a couple of weeks back took 8.8 hours.

### A controlled benchmark

To further test the overhead we ran a controlled benchmark on a Datastax Enterprise node in a single-node cluster. For both vnode enabled/disabled the node was 1) reset, 2) X number of rows were written and then 3) `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp` in Shark was executed a couple of times to get a cold vs. hot cache times. X tested were 10^{0-8}.

Assuming that Shark is not dealing with vnodes in any way, the average (quite stable) overhead for vnodes were ~28 seconds for cold Shark query executions and 17 seconds for hot executions. The latency difference did generally not vary with data size.

All the numbers for the benchmark can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BT-k8RpXEGWk21JiNnsIz3TclMtrOZlBNLk9IaeJ9AU/edit?usp=sharing). All scripts used to run the benchmark (see `output.txt` for usage) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/18aab0579d59f91224a3).

My only guess why there was a difference between "Cold diff" and "Hot diff" (see spreadsheet) is that it took Shark some time to create metadata, but this is simply speculation.

### Conclusion

Our conclusion is that the overhead of vnodes is a constant time between 13 and 30 seconds, independent of data size.

Answer (score 2):

Performance with vnodes and without in the connector should be basically the same. With hadoop each vnode split generated it's own task which created a large amount of overhead.

With Spark, tasks contain the token ranges from multiple vnodes and are merged into a single task and the overall task overhead is lower. There is a slight locality issue where it becomes difficult to get balanced numbers of tasks for all the nodes in the C* cluster with smaller data sizes. This issue is being worked on in SPARKC-43.

Comment: Thanks RussS! Since you are a Datastax dude you might find the benchmark mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29942469/260805 interesting.

Comment: Shark actually will be treating vnodes differently than normal Spark operations since it uses the Hadoop input formats under the hood. It's performance will be much close to the old Hadoop vnodes performance except the per task overhead will be much less.  Thanks for publishing your results.